# Pitfalls at creating new Virtocommerce Store using SDK 1.12

Tags: azure, e-commerce, virtocommerce

**Background**

I have created standard Virtocommerce store and admin (you can see them at 
vcadmin.azurewebsites.net and vcstore.azurewebsites.net -- sorry, I have no enough karma to post more then 2 links)

**Goal**

Thus I started making New Store according to this instructions: docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc1devguide/New+Store+getting+started

**Problem**

I take some errors during this process:

1. After the VC-SDK wa installed, my local store localhost/vcstore began write error http://screencast.com/t/ne0oP3CMfJdB **"Ellastic search server failed"** (meanwile /vcadmin was working properly)
2. After starting new Store via SDK and IIS express, the error **~"can't load MySQLProvider"** was acquired.
3. And after all when I tried to launch CommerceManager for the new Store the error about **~"Path access deny"** was happened: http://screencast.com/t/erTW6vaJ

**Solution**

1. Rebuild solution VirtoCommerce.sln and run setup-search.ps1
2. Just comment strings in the c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config:

   ```
   <!-- add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" ... -->
   ```
3. Using folder properties, give [All] users [Full Acces] to the [c:\Program Files\VirtoCommerce 1.12\SDK\Resources] folder.

Comment: I wouldn't make any changes to any machine.config file. This affects every website on the server and you will probably forget you made a change when you have some related issue in the future. You should override the setting in the site's web.config